# Typescript import from module's subfolder

Tags: typescript

I created myself a npm modules in Typescript, which has the following structure:

```
.
| - src/
|   | - index.ts
|   | - types.d.ts
|   | - utils/
|   |   | - util1.ts
```

And here are the contents:

```
// types.d.ts
export type MyType = string;

---

// index.ts
import { MyType } from './types';

export default (): MyType => 'a string';

---

// utils/util1.ts
export const myFunction = () => 'util string';
```

And tsc compiles these .ts files into the `lib/` folder, which then only contains .js files. It keeps the same inner folder structure.

In my main project, I do:

```
import { myFunction } from 'myModule/lib/utils/util1'
```

However I get an error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'myModule/lib/util/util1'.
```

How can I add types to the compiled JS in the `lib/` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `"declaration": true` in the `tsconfig.json` file of `myModule` will cause `tsc` to generate `.d.ts` files alongside the `.js` files in the `lib` folder, and it should be able to find these files from the main project.